# PyInstaller Failed to execute script, for no reason all of a sudden

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have encountered this very weird issue with PyInstaller, and have no idea how to fix it. Basically all of a sudden when I would compile my python script it would all of a sudden say failed to execute. I changed the filetype from .pyw to .py and disabled -windowed to get the error and this is what I got:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "obfuscator.py", line 36, in
>    File
> "c:\users\lukeb\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
> line 623, in exec_module
> exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)   File "site-packages\pynput_*init*_.py", line 40, in    File
> "c:\users\lukeb\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
> line 623, in exec_module
> exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)   File "site-packages\pynput\keyboard_*init*_.py", line 31, in 
> File "site-packages\pynput_util_*init*_.py", line 76, in backend
> ImportError

Help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Try to move the script (and all files with relative path from that script) to another fresh location. I had this problem and this is what solved it. It appears that some hidden folders (like `.git`) can cause problems in using `pyinstaller` sometimes

Comment: this didnt solve the issue, same error as before by the seems of it.

Comment: @AlexandruDuDu I have just uninstalled everything Python related off my computer, including deleting all the modules, and I still get this error. But if I run the build process in a virtual machine with the same stuff, it works fine.

Comment: that's strange. I think it's related to a library version in this case. Maybe you can play around with verions of `pynput` and `pyimod03`. Try to downgrade them (or use the latest version of them if you're not)

Comment: @AlexandruDuDu On the virtual machine I am using the current versions of that package, same with my baremetal machine. However I have completely reinstalled the module and it's done nothing. I'm really thinking of going nuclear and resetting Windows.

Comment: I believe it's more than just a python issue, I'm going to try run a successful build of the script to see if its a problem during building or executing now.